# Pull specific line from every .txt file in folder and output lines to another .txt

Tags: python

I have a folder of 400 .txt files and am attempting to take the sixth line from every file in the directory, and output each line all into a new singular .txt file with the sixth line from each file listed one after the other in the new file. For example, the output I am attempting to create should look like:

```
**output.txt**
This is the sixth line from 1.txt
This is the sixth line from 2.txt
This is the sixth line from 3.txt
```

So far I'm able to print off all the files in the directory in a list to be acted upon with:

```
import os
entries = os.listdir(r'C:/Users/defaultuser/Desktop/UprocScripts')
for entry in entries:
    print(entry)
```

I have researched and tried various combinations of the `readlines()` method, but I'm not sure exactly how to combine them in multiples over an entire directory of 400 files. I'm still trying to learn, any ideas if I'm on the right path and how to combine them is appreciated.

Comment: Could you put us a sample code from what you've done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way if you want to use `for loop` for iterating over your text file and pick a specific line.In this code all the **.txt** files are fetched at the beginning.

```
import glob
list_of_txt = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\defaultuser\Desktop\UprocScripts\*.txt")
for textfiles in list_of_txt:
    with open(r"C:\Users\defaultuser\Desktop\UprocScripts\final.txt", 'a+') as final_text_file:
        with open(textfiles, 'r') as textFile:
            for n, line in enumerate(textFile):
                if n+1 == 6: # if it's line no. 6 then write it on your final txt file
                    final_text_file.writelines(line)
```

Also note that I am using the **glob** module here. In addition if you want to add "from some.txt" after each line then just replace the last line with this:

```
final_text_file.write(line.strip() + " from " + textfiles.split('\\')[-1] + "\r\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read each file, get the sixth line from each of them, then write that line to the output file.

Like so:

```
import os
entries = os.listdir(r'C:/Users/defaultuser/Desktop/UprocScripts')
for entry in entries:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        with open(entry) as text_file:
            lines = text_file.readlines()
            target_line = lines[5]  # sixth line
        out_file.write(target_line)
```

Note this does read the complete file for each of the input files- which might be inefficient. You can try to get around that by trying to utilize the `hint` parameter to `readlines` - which accepts an approximate number of bytes to read until. If you know the apprx size of each line (in bytes) you can pass `6 * line_size` as `hint` to try & optimize the read part.

Comment: Thanks! I tried a few variations of the with-open-as combination but couldn't put it all together. I appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read all the file, you can read only the first 6 lines like this:

```
import os
entries = os.listdir(r'C:/Users/defaultuser/Desktop/UprocScripts')
final = []
for entry in entries

# Read the first 6 lines and add the last one (you don't need to read everything):

    with open(entry) as f:
        lines = []
        for _ in range(6):
            lines.append(f.readline())
    final.append(lines[-1])

# And write

with open("final.txt", "r") as f:
   f.writelines(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os


files_list = []
sixth_line_list = []
output_list = []
directory = 'C:\\Users\\defaultuser\\Desktop\\UprocScripts'

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        files_list.append(''.join([directory, '\\', file]))

for file in files_list:
    with open(file, 'r') as file_:
        sixth_line_list.append({file: file_.readlines()[5]})

for i in range(0, len(sixth_line_list), 1):
    output_list.append(''.join([sixth_line_list[i].values()[0], ' from ', sixth_line_list[i].keys()[0]]))

with open(''.join([directory, '\\output.txt']), 'w') as output:
    output.writelines(output_list)
```